# Sometimes need to double click links

Tags: sifr

On occasion I need to click a sIFR link in order to "activate" it.  I hover over it and nothing happens.  I click it, then hover over it and then it works correctly.  This seems to mostly happen with items that are not within the viewport when the page renders (items you have to scroll to see).  Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This tends to be a problem in Firefox when you have a Flash movie with `wmode` set to `transparent` or `opaque`, contained in a `float`ed element. Removing the wmode should resolve the issue.

Comment: That's a bummer.  The wmode has to be transparent as the background color changes with various scenarios.  Oh well.  Thanks for the tip though, much appreciated.